# Summing very large numbers in Racket

Tags: lisp, racket

So I am looking to sum up the numbers between zero and one hundred million. This code works extremely well for ten million, executing on my machine in about 3 seconds. However as soon as I attempt to sum up to one hundred million, it freezes my computer along with never finishing. I have waited for this code to finish for five minutes and yet it still will not finish.

```
#lang racket/base

(require (only-in racket/list range))

(let ([theList (range 0 100000000)]) (time (apply + theList)))
```

Comment: That's hardly a surprise, given the amount of memory this will use. I guess your system is also paging?

Comment: Well, I was expecting only a 10-15x increase in slowdown from the ten million version. I implemented this exact same function in Clojure and it finishes fine on my computer in only 17 seconds for one hundred million. Do you have any suggestions on turning off paging?

Comment: Clojure evaluates this list lazily, but Racket does not (at least not in the way you wrote it). For Racket you need to change the code, look at Chris' example.

Comment: I'm not into Racket but gonna shoot my point, could this be related to x86/x64 architecture issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `for/sum`:

```
(for/sum ([i (in-range 100000000)])
  i)
```

Like all of the `for/xxx` variations, `for/sum` is essentially implemented in terms of `for/fold` (which Chris Jester-Young explained). In other words `for/sum` is a convenience wrapper around `for/fold`.

Comment: I'll call this one the answer because is it works exactly the same as Chris' but is slightly better syntactically. Thanks to both of you guys!

Comment: @user1976901 thank you for accepting my answer. Although mine is more specific, Chris Jester-Young's is worth knowing. If `for/sum` didn't already exist, you could do what you wanted using `for/fold`. In fact you could even define a `for/sum` form _exactly_ like the one Racket provides--which is one of the many great things about Racket.

Comment: You're welcome! If I remember correctly for/sum expands out into for/fold. Yes macros are a joy, thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to sum numbers in Racket, to my knowledge, is to use `for/fold` rather than `apply`, if your range is huge:

```
(for/fold ((n 0))
          ((i (in-range 100000000)))
  (+ n i))
```

This takes half a second to run on my computer.